# C error reading packet from streaming socket

Tags: c, sockets

I'm just playing around with streaming sockets in C, but I'm having an issue reading the data packet returned from a server application. The code below shows the structure which is used on the client and server side.

```
struct packet
{
    uint16_t f1;
    uint16_t f2;
    uint32_t f3;
    uint16_t pf1;
    uint32_t pf2;
};
```

Server side for sending:

```
char buffer[14];
struct packet myPacket;

myPacket.f1 = 2321;
myPacket.f2 = 4423;
myPacket.f3 = 2134;
myPacket.pf1 = 765;
myPacket.pf2 = 9867;

htonPacket(myPacket, buffer);
```

Function for packing data into buffer.

```
void htonPacket(struct packet h, char buffer[14]) {
    uint16_t u16;
    uint32_t u32;

    u16 = htons(h.f1);
    memcpy(buffer+0, &u16, 2);

    u16 = htons(h.f2);
    memcpy(buffer+2, &u16, 2);

    u32 = htonl(h.f3);
    memcpy(buffer+4, &u32, 4);

    u16 = htons(h.pf1);
    memcpy(buffer+8, &u16, 2);

    u32 = htonl(h.pf2);
    memcpy(buffer+10, &u32, 4);
}
```

Client side for unpacking and printing:

```
void ntohPacket(struct packet* h, char buffer[14]) {
    uint16_t u16;
    uint32_t u32;

    memcpy(&u16, buffer+0, 2);
    h->f1 = ntohs(u16);

    memcpy(&u16, buffer+2, 2);
    h->f2 = ntohs(u16);

    memcpy(&u32, buffer+4, 4);
    h->f3 = ntohl(u32);

    memcpy(&u16, buffer+6, 2);
    h->pf1 = ntohs(u16);

    memcpy(&u32, buffer+8, 4);
    h->pf2 = ntohl(u32);
}
```

Printing unpacked data:

```
printf("myPacket.f1: %d\n", myPacket.f1);
printf("myPacket.f2: %d\n", myPacket.f2);
printf("myPacket.f3: %d\n", myPacket.f3);
printf("myPacket.pf1: %d\n", myPacket.pf1);
printf("myPacket.pf2: %d\n", myPacket.pf2);
```

When I print the values, it becomes apparent that I've had some issue either addressing or writing to the wrong memory location, but I can't seem to find the error.

```
myPacket.f1: 2321
myPacket.f2: 4423
myPacket.f3: 2134
myPacket.pf1: 2134
myPacket.pf2: 50135040
```

Comment: Why all the dance with copying stuff from one struct into a variable, then adjust endianness, and memcpy? You could just do `dst->f1 = htons(src->f1)` in one go. It is much easier to just have `struct`s to handle stuff, not fool around with individual bytes (sure, you have to be careful that the compiler doesn't sneak padding in). I think that redoing your code that way will fix your problem.

Comment: I'm learning and I was just expanding on an example I found on the packet stuff. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @vonbrand: post that as an answer and you'll get a +vote from me ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are using different offsets for your `memcpy` operations, so of course you get garbage...

```
memcpy(buffer+0, &u16, 2);
memcpy(buffer+2, &u16, 2);
memcpy(buffer+4, &u32, 4);
memcpy(buffer+8, &u16, 2);
memcpy(buffer+10, &u32, 4);
```

vs.

```
memcpy(&u16, buffer+0, 2);
memcpy(&u16, buffer+2, 2);
memcpy(&u32, buffer+4, 4);
memcpy(&u16, buffer+6, 2);
memcpy(&u32, buffer+8, 4);
```

Your last lines in `ntohPacket` should read

```
memcpy(&u16, buffer+8, 2);
h->pf1 = ntohs(u16);

memcpy(&u32, buffer+10, 4);
h->pf2 = ntohl(u32);
```

Comment: Doh, thanks. After correcting, however, something more interesting came up. Now the last value is slightly different from what I'm expecting.  myPacket.pf2: 9728 When I'm sending 9867.

Comment: I'd just do what @vonbrand suggested (in his comment). Maintaining all these indices is bound to cause you untold pain someday.

Answer (score 1):

Your memcpy offsets are wrong. Fixed:

```
memcpy(&u16, buffer+0, 2);
h->f1 = ntohs(u16);

memcpy(&u16, buffer+2, 2);
h->f2 = ntohs(u16);

memcpy(&u32, buffer+4, 4);
h->f3 = ntohl(u32);

memcpy(&u16, buffer+8, 2);  <-- here
h->pf1 = ntohs(u16);

memcpy(&u32, buffer+10, 4);  <-- here
h->pf2 = ntohl(u32);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why all the dance with copying stuff from one struct into a variable, then adjust endianness, and memcpy? You could just do `dst->f1 = htons(src->f1)` in one go. It is much easier to just have `struct`s to handle stuff, not fool around with individual bytes (sure, you have to be careful that the compiler doesn't sneak padding in). I think that redoing your code that way will fix your problem.